# Snippet stand alone

Tags: feature-request

Since Stack Overflow now have a snippet functionality I still see lots of external editors usage (like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)).

I would suggest to also give Stack Overflow Snippet as a separate link that you can share (so you can use Stack Overflow Snippet in comments too).

Also I think there should be much wider [plugins](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) support, like [Bootstrap](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) or jQuery UI.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Why wouldn't you just share a link to the question/answer?

Comment: @Stijn Use case: OP issue is that his code does not work, you give jsfiddle link instead of internal resource link.

Comment: Stack Snippets show up within the post itself, which is what we want. We don't want to have to go to other sites/pages to get the answer. Making Stack Snippets another site would only encourage people to leave link-only answers since it would be on the site itself.

Comment: @Mike the idea seems not to be to link to a stack snippet from an answer or question, but rather to be able to utilize the stack snippet functionality in a link in a comment. This could definitely be useful in situations where the code you're providing is not actually an answer to the question, but more tangential, or in cases where the OP's code actually works as intended and you want to show the OP that.

Comment: @TinyGiant why it should be a stacksnippet?

Comment: @Braiam because that iis what the op is suggesting, with the reasoning that it would be hosted by stack overflow, so there would be no worrying about linking to external resources that cannot be controlled. JSFiddle might go out of business and shut down their servers at any point and all references to content stored on those servers would be rendered meaningless.

Comment: @TinyGiant are you aware that the domain hosts nothing, right? The hosting is done on SO posts and the domain is just there as security measure. This would represent a cost of allowing stacksnippets domain to host stuff separately of SO and all the whistles.

Comment: @Braiam are you aware that you just restated the proposal?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan There could be some pop-up window that shows a snippet from comment rather than leaving current page.